# Swift UI Toggle inside of a toolbar Menu

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu, toggle, toolbar

I can't seem to get a switch toggle to work inside of a Menu placed in the toolbar.  I did notice that if I do not set the .toggleStyle(.switch) it will allow you to toggle on and off with a check mark.  I would like the traditional switch style however.  I have tried creating custom buttons, labels images to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated. (**Edit** - Will need the solution to be compatible with iOS 15.0)

```
struct TestingView: View {
    @State var isToggled: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("List Goes Here")
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                        Menu{
                            Toggle("Test", isOn:$isToggled)
                                .toggleStyle(.switch)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                                .font(.title3)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    }
}

struct TestingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestingView()
    }
}`
```

[with switch enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuKcG.png)

[with out .toggleStyle(.switch)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mywki.png)

I have tried Labels, Buttons, Images, Building a Custom toggle but there seems to be a problem inside of the menu.  I would expect a slider like the below within the menu:

[Normal Toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1MSy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a `.popover` instead of `Menu`?
Like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingView: View {
    @State var isToggled: Bool = false
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("List Goes Here")
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }
                        .popover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                            Toggle("Test", isOn:$isToggled)
                                .presentationCompactAdaptation((.popover))
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
        }

    }
}

struct TestingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestingView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution, unfortunately in my case this would require ios 16.4 and I need to be compatible back to at least ios 15.0. apologies for not adding that in the original problem statement.  I will edit the original so that it states such.  I will continue to look into possibilities with popover menu.